# how to store List<String> or any List type in solr riak

Tags: solr, riak, yokozuna

I am using riak nosql database with solr.
I know that how to index field in solr with following basic type 
index int value with suffix _i 
index String value with suffix _s
index long value with suffix _l
like this.

Now I want to index List in solr. How can I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention for multi-valued fields (i.e. lists) is *_ls for longs, *_ss for Strings, *_fs for floats, etc. For example, if an object's field `letters_ss` contains `['A', 'B']`, the object can be found in any of the following ways: `letters_ss:A`, `letters_ss:B`, or even `letters_ss:A AND letters_ss:B`.

Alternatively, you can create a custom schema that would match your datatype and not rely on the naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But if suppose I have user defined class say Employee and I want to store this class as a list of object. like this, List<Employee> . How do I store it in solr.